# Can I use a third party scala library in java?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I recently wanted to develop a spark project in Java and interact with Hbase. I found a third party library called **spark hbase connector**, but it is written in Scala. Can I just use classes from this library in Java directly or should I make a scala-java mixed project?

Thanks for your attention, I am not very familiar with this part.

Comment: http://blog.muhuk.com/2016/05/24/how_to_call_scala_from_java__using_scala_classes.html#.WV44DOvythE

Comment: @Adam thanks,but I still have a question, now that we can call scala functions in java, is that necessary for project like spark to provide a java api？why don't we just use scala API in java code

Comment: @zpwpal you can always use Scala API from java directly,  but the difference in the language and extra features of Scala mean that an API designed for Scala but not for java can be ugly,  hard to use, and unreadable depending on what Scala features are used. If a Scala library designer wants their API top be used with Java as well they need to plan for it.

Comment: @puhlen thanks for answering, it helped me a lot

Comment: @puhlen thank you . I did as you say and it works well

Answer (score 3):

You can, a class is a class whether it's defined in scala or Java or Kotlin or literally any JVM language provided the data types are compatible.